# read() function is stuck and freezes without response

Tags: c++

I'm building a client server project. At this part of the code:

```
int client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (client_socket == -1) {
    //error
    std::cerr << "Could not create a socket"<<std::endl;
    return -1;
}

//We need to create a sockaddr obj to hold address of server
sockaddr_in address; //in means IP4
address.sin_family = AF_INET;//IP4
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");  //the localhost address
address.sin_port = htons(port);
//we need to convert our number (both port & localhost)
// to a number that the network understands.

// Requesting a connection with the server on local host with port 8081
int is_connect = connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
if (is_connect == -1) {
    std::cerr << "Could not connect to host server"<<std::endl;
    return -2;
} else {
    std::cout<<"Client is now connected to server" <<std::endl;
}
int is_sent = send(client_socket , hello.c_str() , hello.length() , 0 );
if (is_sent == -1) {
    std::cout<<"Error sending message"<<std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout<<"Hello message sent to server" <<std::endl;
}
char buffer[1024] = {0};
int valread = read( client_socket , buffer, 1024);
std::cout<<buffer<<std::endl
```

The client_socket has value 3, which is right, and it prints hello message sent to server. After that, the thread is stuck on the `read()` function!  Any ideas?

update 
this is the python script that receives:

```
def handle_input(client_input):
    """
    :param str client_input:
    """
    try:
        param_name, param_value = parse_client_input(client_input)
        variable = get_gear_variable(param_name)
        if variable is not None:
            variable.var_value = float(param_value)
            logging.info('Setting %s to value %f', param_name, param_value)
        else:
            logging.warning('Variable %s was not found', param_name)
    except ValueError as e:
        logging.error(e.args[0])


def server(): #handles input from client
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('', args.listen_port))
    s.listen(args.socket_backlog)
    logging.info('Listening on 0.0.0.0:%d', args.listen_port)
    clientSocket, address = s.accept()
    logging.info('Accepted a connection from %s:%d', *address)
    server = ServerSock(clientSocket)
    while True:
        print("In server waiting for data")
        msg = server.recv()
        logging.debug('msg from client: %s', msg)
        handle_input(msg)
```

I posted only the relevant function

Comment: Read is supposed to wait until it gets anything to read (in this case, a message from the other side of the connection) or the file descriptor / socket closes.

Comment: if you do not want read to block look into nonblocking io, you may also want to look into functions like select and poll to detect when you can read or write without blocking.

Comment: Set the timeout for read or select before read

Comment: well, I need it to be a blocking call, and I checked the script that receives the sent message but its not receiving although the connection happened between them

Comment: @mohannadabuahmad What does the server expect you to send to it to get a reply back? Does your `hello` variable contain any kind of terminator in it, such as a line break? I'm guessing it does not. That may make the server wait for a terminator and not send a reply back to your client. That could explain why `read()` is not receiving any data. On a side note, `read()` does not null-terminate the `buffer` you give it, but your code assumes it does. So either null-terminate the `buffer` explicitly before giving it to `cout`, or better use `cout.write(buffer, valread)` instead of `cout << buffer`

Comment: the hello contains a string to the other side that will parse it, string is "set /sim/time/warp 3200"
the server is stuck on recv() waiting for something, and the variable is_sent = 10 like it sent the bytes

Comment: @mohannadabuahmad but, HOW does the server expect that string to be delimited exactly? TCP is a byte stream, it has no concept of messages, like UDP does, so any message you send MUST be delimited in some way so that the receiver knows where one message ends and the next begins. That means either 1) sending a message's length before sending the message's data, or 2) sending a unique terminator at the end of each message, such as a line break or null terminator

Comment: wait I'll check

Comment: I added this hardcoded 
hello = "set /sim/time/warp 3200 \n" ;
still the same

Comment: btw I'm sending a message lenght from the start if you see the hello.lentgh() in send function

Comment: @mohannadabuahmad that only tells `send()` how many bytes to send, that does not send the value of the length to the server. When I say send the length before the data, I'm referring more to something like `uint32_t len = htonl(hello.length()); send(client_socket, (char*)&len, sizeof(len), 0); send(client_socket, hello.c_str(), hello.length(), 0);`. Do you have access to the server code? Can you show its reading logic? Or at least documentation for the communication?

Comment: its a python script

    print("In server waiting for data")
    msg = server.recv()
    logging.debug('msg from client: %s', msg)
    handle_input(msg)

I can't change it and its stuck on recv() waiting for message

Comment: @mohannadabuahmad Then please [edit] your question to show the actual python script. Based on what you describe, there is no way `recv()` can be blocked waiting for data, since your client is actually sending some data. So there is another factor at play here that you have not descibed yet.

Comment: ok, updated here

Comment: it worked!!!! after adding "\r\n" to the message
thanks a lot, put it as an answer so others can find the solution easy

Comment: @mohannadabuahmad In `server = ServerSock(clientSocket)`, where and how is `ServerSock()` defined? Python's native `socket.recv()` does not require a line break, had you been calling `recv()` directly on the `clientSocket` that `s.accept()` returns. Which makes me think that `ServerSock()` is adding an extra layer to the mix, probably returning a new object that implements its own `recv()` to read linebreak-delimited strings by calling `clientSocket.recv()` in a loop until a line break is received. Can you confirm that?

Comment: its fine maybe u didn't see my previous comment

Comment: @mohannadabuahmad Yes, I saw it. But I want you to understand WHY it is needed to work that way

Comment: haha true, actually I didn't read that cause I thought u still trying to help solve it, thanks really appreciate that

Comment: check this:


class ServerSock:
    NEWLINE = '\r\n'
    RECV_CHUNK = 4096

    def __init__(self, sock):
        self.buff = ''
        self.sock = sock

    def recv(self):
        """
        :rtype str:
        """
        newline_idx = self.buff.find(self.NEWLINE)





      u see

Comment: but I have a simple question, I don't see that the script is trying to send anything after he receive the mssg, so why should I expect a read()!